# How can I remove an app icon located in the lower row in my Pixel 6's home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-pixel-6

How can I remove an app icon located in the lower row in my Pixel 6's home screen?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Morrison Chang](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3573/morrison-chang) [commented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246044/how-can-i-remove-an-app-icon-located-in-the-lower-row-in-my-pixel-6s-home-scree/246233#comment329121_246044), one can tap and hold the icon and drag off/upward from the "shortcut bar", which sometimes reveals a "remove" option. The "remove" option doesn't work for me, but if one can tap and hold the icon a second time, it then reveals a "Don't suggest app" option, which worked for me.

Demo: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Zg0OCC0ocQQ

"Don't suggest app" option:

[image]

To undo it: Press and hold the home screen, then choose home settings, then suggestions, then blocked apps  ([source](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/139290842/revert-app-suggestion-in-app-drawer?hl=en)).